# The view mysite.views.Attendancecreate didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

I am trying to create an attendance system for a list of employees ,

#### Models

```py
attendance_choices = (
    ('absent', 'Absent'),
    ('present', 'Present')
)

class Head_of_department(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name 

class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    head_of_department = models.ForeignKey('Head_of_department', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Attendance(models.Model):
    head_of_department = models.ForeignKey('Head_of_department', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    attendance = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=attendance_choices, blank=True)
```

#### Views

```py
class Attendancecreate(CreateView):
    model = Attendance
    fields = ['employee']
    success_url = '/dashboard/'

    def get_context_data(self,** kwargs):
        context = super(Attendancecreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = AttendanceFormset(queryset=Attendance.objects.none(), instance=Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email), initial=[{'employee': employee} for employee inself.get_initial()['employee']])
        context['attendance_form'] = Attendanceform()
        email = self.request.user.email
        hod = Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email)
        context["employees"] = Employee.objects.filter(head_of_department =hod)
        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        email = self.request.user.email
        hod = Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email)
        initial = super(Attendancecreate , self).get_initial()
        initial['employee'] = Employee.objects.filter(head_of_department=hod)
        return initial

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = AttendanceFormset(request.POSTqueryset=Attendance.objects.none(), instance=Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email), initial=[{'employee': employee} for employee inself.get_initial()['employee']))
        if formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset)

     def form_valid(self, formset):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.head_of_department = get_object_or_404(Head_of_department, email=self.request.user.email)
            instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
     def form_invalid(self, formset):
        print ('errors')
        print (formset.errors)
```

#### Forms

```py
class Attendanceform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ('employee','attendance','hod')

AttendanceFormset = inlineformset_factory(Head_of_department,Attendance,fields=('attendance',))
```

#### Template

```html
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
{{ form }}
<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

#### Error

Below shown square brackets was printed in the console when I used print(formset.errors)

```
[]
```

I am getting a value error

```
The view mysite.views.Attendancecreate didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I am trying to achieve the below view , listing the employees and marking attendance , I was able to list the employees , but after marking attendance and submitting it is triggering the above mentioned error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formset isn't valid and missing `request.POST`

```
class Attendancecreate(CreateView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = AttendanceFormset(
            request.POST,
            queryset=Attendance.objects.none(), 
            instance=Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email), 
            initial=[{'employee': employee} for employee inself.get_initial()['employee'])
        )
        if formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset)
        return self.form_invalid(formset)

    def form_invalid(self, formset):
        print (formset.errors) # Will print the error in terminal
```

#### Template

```html
{{ formset.management_form }}
   {% for form in formset %}
      {{ form.employee.initial }} {{ form.employee}}  {{ form.attendance }}
<br><br>
   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *views* in *Django* are expected to return `HttpResponse` as result, but the overridden `post` method doesn't return any `HttpResponse` if the formset isn't valid.

You can give feedback to user when the formset isn't valid like below.

```
class Attendancecreate(CreateView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = AttendanceFormset(
            request.data,
            queryset=Attendance.objects.none(), 
            instance=Head_of_department.objects.get(email=email), 
            initial=[{'employee': employee} for employee inself.get_initial()['employee'])
        )
        if formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(formset)
        return self.form_invalid(formset)

    def form_invalid(self, formset):
        response_kwargs = {'content_type': self.content_type}
        context = {'errors': formset.errors}
        return self.response_class(
            request=self.request,
            template=self.get_template_names(),
            context=context,
            using=self.template_engine,
            **response_kwargs
        )
```

Comment: but this give feedback only , how can i make it valid ? your answer only give feedback , i need to post the attendance , how can i do that?

Comment: @Coder13 I've added `form_invalid` to my answer.

Comment: i have updated the code , i was missing ```request.POST``` in ```def post``` , but now the rendered employee is not passed while marking attendance i.e , the employee field is blank after submitting the form

Comment: @Coder13 I think my last edit will solve your problem. Let's check it!

Comment: no need of form_invalid , the only thing I was missing was request.POST

Comment: @Coder13 I don't think so. In case of the formset is invalid, the `post` method returns nothing! So the exception will be happend. The missing `request.POST` is another problem which I've included in my answer!